# Zune 4.7 on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, zune, zune-software

Has anyone had any luck getting this to work? 
I've tried

- Extracting the packages and running the .msi directly
- Running in compatibility mode (assorted flavours)
- Standard install
- I've also tried the full download as well as the version that downloads during the install

I'm pretty much out of ideas.

Comment: You might explain what "not work" means, be specific.

Comment: It's not supported on 2008, the standard install refuses to run. Extracting the package installs it but it fails setting a firewall rule and then doesn't work :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with a workaround...
 1. Install Windows 7 on a Hyper-V VM
 2. Install Zune on VM
 3. Install http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/ (I also tried http://www.usb-over-network.com/usb-over-network-download.html but it wouldn't recognise my phone)
 4. Connect my phone to my laptop and configure USB over Ethernet between the laptop and the VM
 5. Setup WiFi syncing between Zune software and my phone

Answer (score 2):

It is **not supported** on Microsoft Windows Server operating systems...perhaps run a virtual machine on Windows Server 2008 R2  and install it in there?

Supported Zune Software 4.7 operating systems:

> Windows 7; Windows Vista; Windows XP Media Center Edition 2005 Update Rollup 2; Windows XP Service Pack 3

*Source:* http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ab1a80ed-e337-4346-9d5a-f00cfb467514

Comment: I know, often not supported doesn't mean won't work though. The problem with a VM is USB passthrough is tricky/impossible to get working at least in Hyper-v I'm looking at a few ways of getting this to work though (I really only need the USB to work once then I can wifi sync) Shouldn't be this hard though!